# d3js / jQuery selector does not work

Tags: jquery, css, svg, jquery-selectors

So I have this SVG, and I want to select all paths that have a certain attribute with a certain value. Specifically the attribute key is "NEN2580" and the value can be a number of things.

So lets say we have a set of paths similar to:

```
<path style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); fill: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: black; stroke-width: 0.25px; background-color: white;" d="M486.623,219.237 L486.375,217.624 L454.744,222.999 L454.972,224.497 L455.785,230.259 L456.344,235.117 L456.471,236.294 L457.993,236.122 L458.354,235.678 L459.039,236.234 L457.298,238.38 L462.863,242.894 L469.513,242.52 L469.228,237.441 L465.083,237.079 L465.16,236.2 L470.067,236.629 L470.395,242.471 L489.055,241.423 L488.64,236.886 L488.513,235.176 L488.369,233.611 L487.935,228.895 L487.716,226.954 L487.502,225.366 L486.623,219.237" guid="3e_Z0UB95FzQ84RHxlySDx" _id="3e_Z0UB95FzQ84RHxlySDx" type="IfcSpace" name="Cel" number="A1.01" ruimtefunctie="" toegankelijkheid="false" area="11.58914065878" NEN2580="Nuttige ruimte" ancestors="1EbDErTW54e9tQrrOBatzH,1EbDErTW54e9tQrrRq52Ux,1EbDErTW54e9tQrrRq52Uu,1EbDErTW54e9tQrrRq52Uw"></path>
```

I had this code which I was sure to work, but it doesn't:

```
d3.selectAll("path[NEN2580='Nuttige ruimte']").style({fill: 'rgb(41, 128, 185)'});
```

Also changing it to the following does not work:

```
$("path[NEN2580='Nuttige ruimte']").css("fill", "rgb(41, 128, 185)");
```

Is it impossible to select for keys that end with numbers? Only thing I can come up with, but I could not find any constraints in css selector documentation for attribute keys that end with numbers.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The attribute you're using `NEN2580` is not a valid SVG attribute. To make it valid, you could define a custom XML namespace and reference that namespace in your `<svg>` tag. (The other attributes in your example have the same problem.) Because it's not valid, browsers aren't parsing it, so JavaScript can't select based on it.

Comment: Browsers parse all attributes.

Comment: They parse all HTML attributes (otherwise Angular would never fly) but not SVG. Change the `NEN2580` to `id` for example and the OP's code works fine. (I verified with a jsfiddle but didn't save it.)

Comment: id is lower case NEN2580 is not.

Comment: I query succesfully for the ruimtefunctie attribute. e.g. `d3.selectAll("path[ruimtefunctie='functieruimte']").style({fill: 'rgb(26, 188, 156)'});`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're doing this in html (rather than XML) the attribute needs to be [lower case in the selector](http://jsfiddle.net/longsonr/05zgwztz/1/) (html is not case sensitive)

```
$("path[nen2580='Nuttige ruimte']").css("fill", "rgb(41, 128, 185)");
```

Comment: No avail either :S Thanks for the idea though

Comment: Works for me on Firefox. Did you try the jsfiddle in the answer?

Answer (score 0):

since the attributes of the SVG are dynamically generated from a noSQL database, which is populated through another service, the name of the attribute was in capitols, NEN2580. I changed the database to write the attribute in lower case, like nen2580, and that did the trick.

Weird though that when it is in capitols, querying for lowercase does not work, but when it is in lower case as attribute, querying for capitols does not seem to matter.

So:

**What doesnt work:**

svg:

```
<path NEN2580="Nuttige ruimte">
```

js:

```
$("path[NEN2580='Nuttige ruimte']").css("fill", "rgb(1,1,1)")
$("path[nen2580='Nuttige ruimte']").css("fill", "rgb(1,1,1)")
```

**What works:**

svg:

```
<path nen2580="Nuttige ruimte">
```

js:

```
$("path[NEN2580='Nuttige ruimte']").css("fill", "rgb(1,1,1)")
$("path[nen2580='Nuttige ruimte']").css("fill", "rgb(1,1,1)")
```